# Split a string with regex based on number of characters and spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need to split a string into an array, based on a number of characters and without cutting off a word.

I've been using this:

```
var charPerLine = 17;
var regex = new RegExp('^(.{'+charPerLine+'}\\S*\\s+', 'g');
var output = str.replace(regex, "$&@").split(/\s+@/);
```

The issue with this code is that sometimes I get a string longer than 17 characters, in the case the space was close to the latest character.

For example,

```
var str = "I want you to do something else instead.";
```

Gets split into:

```
var output = ["I want you to do something", "else instead."]
```

But the first string is more than 17 characters, I need it to be split such as:

```
var output = ["I want you to do", "something else", "instead."]
```

It must also work with punctuations and single/double quotes

Any suggestion?

Comment: Question: What happens if a single word has more than 15 characters?  Does it get split somewhere, or do we eat it?

Comment: That should never happen, so I would say it shouldn't be cut off in the middle

Answer (score 4):

```
(?=(\b.{1,17}\b))\1
```

You can use this and replace by `$1\n`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/ff7iZp/1

Comment: This has a slightly different behavior btw. It finds the *last* possible break opportunity *within* 17 chars, while the OP's regex finds the *first* possible break opportunity *after* 17 chars. This may be desirable though.

Comment: @alexmngn can u provide an example

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ff7iZp/2 - Final punctuation goes to next line, and some sentences starts with a space.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a word-boundary assertion `\b` to the first regex, so that it won't advance with `\S*` if it is currently at the start of a new word:

```js
var str = "I want you to do something else instead";

var charPerLine = 15;
var regex = new RegExp('.{'+charPerLine+'}(?:\\b|\\S*\\s+)', 'g');
var output = str.replace(regex, "$&@").split(/\s*@\s*/);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks, I really appreciate it. It feels good to be in the "k"s rep club (just got it) ;)

Comment: Don't expect a catered limo ride with Jon Skeet, but yeah, it's a big accomplishment :-)

Comment: For some reason this adds `@` in the middle of sentences. `var string = 'It\'s easy to get into and it doesn\'t take much effort, but long-term it always leaves you wanting more.'; output = [ 'It\'s easy to get@ into and it doesn\'t', 'take much effort@, but long-term', 'it always leaves@ you wanting more@.' ]`

Comment: @alexmngn I made a change to the second regex to fix that.