# Split a string based on a specific number of characters in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, split

I have been looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059971/split-a-string-in-vb-net) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276245/split-a-string-with-regex-based-on-number-of-characters-and-spaces) which work with letters.  This isn't exactly what I'm aiming for.

I will be receiving 8 varied numbers.  I need to split them at specific points, then insert a forward slash.

Example:

Incoming `01012001` needs to equal `01/01/2001`

I have been working on something like this, even though I know it's not completed.

```
        Dim dateString As String = Search_.IssuedDT.ToShortDateString
        Dim forwardSlash As Char = "/"
        Dim correctedString As String() = dateString.Split()
```

Bottom line, I have to add a forward slash between characters 2 and 3, and 4 and 5.

Comment: Is the "incoming" data specifically a date?

Comment: So these should be dates, that's what it looks like to me?

Comment: yes, but the user does not want to place the slashes in. so, i get to fix that

Comment: `Dim dt As Date Date.TryParse(yourstring, dt)` if a success then use the `format or tostring` to format it the way you want

Comment: ...seriously?  Being new to VB.Net is not helping syntax

Comment: Seriously what? You are messing with dates and the tryparse will confirm that.

Comment: it's that easy..... wow  i'm more mad at myself.

Comment: this would have saved me several hours.

Comment: Yes that's it, happy programming!

Comment: Thank you so much!  if you create an answer, i'll give it a little ol' green check

Comment: I'm not worried about it, it was simple  just close the question out...

Comment: you got it!  thank you so much!

Comment: My guess is you are going to end up with a bunch of bad data unless you provide some restraints on what strings the user can enter. Just cause you can parse it doesn't mean the intended date is the date that gets accepted by the code.

Comment: i mean that might be the case, but the person that will be using this just happens to be the owner of the site and the sole user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful about parsing dates: a few countries use month-day-year and many others use day-month-year.

To give you an idea of what is possible:

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim s = "31012001"
        Dim d As DateTime
        d = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "ddMMyyyy", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

        ' if you need a string representation of the date:
        Dim q = d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

        Console.WriteLine(q)

        ' leaving the date as a date, as it should be, and presenting it as a string:
        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))

        s = "01312001" ' not in ddMMyyyy format
        If DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "ddMMyyyy", Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, d) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Converted successfully as " & d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Could not parse " & s & " as dd/MM/yyyy")
        End If


        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: it's just the US that is using this.  talked to the lead about that immediately.

Comment: but you're absolutely right, if this were a bigger site with a global clientele, you're hitting the nail right on the head

Comment: @KevinFischer If the program is only to be used in the US then change where I used "dd" to "MM" and conversely the "MM" to "dd". N.B. "MM" means month and "mm" means minutes.

Comment: @KevinFischer I recommend that you use the `TryParseExact` method as it makes it easy to catch a typo like "1225216" where the user missed the "0" out, and so on.

Comment: Very helpful.  Thank you!

Comment: This isn't code review, I can't believe you answered this without explaining where the OP is going wrong besides expanding on a suggestion in the comments. On another note why I didn't bother is because there are only thousands of related questions we don't need another one, it would have been best to close the question.

Comment: @Zaggler My question (the first comment) and the OP's reply (the third comment) were sufficient for me to formulate an answer which solved the actual problem: a date (in string format) needed to be parsed such that it could be rendered in a different format. In the answer, I was able to also provide a method which offers some detection of bad data input.

Comment: So the other related items is not sufficient enough that you still had to write an answer? Date.TryParse is sufficient enough , OP didn't mention about other formats from other countries. It was also mentioned the format could be anything he would like. Your answer is just an expansion of comments and already related answers here on SO... As mentioned why didn't you post a comment to the other 1000s of related questions with answers instead of adding another?

Comment: @Zaggler If you find a suitable duplicate, I'll be happy to vote to close it as such. The idea is not necessarily to provide an answer specific to the question, but hopefully to give an answer which can be helpful to other people - my answer should be generalisable to fairly similar questions.

Comment: On another note, what if the string doesn't correspond to the format in  `d = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "ddMMyyyy", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` parseexact will throw an exception...

Comment: @Zaggler Maybe it doesn't appear on your screen, but I also showed using `TryParseExact` to test for bad input data and presenting (some sort of) an error message.

Comment: Voting you up because I have no issue answering a poorly formed question.

Comment: @djv this is a reason SO has the questions they do because people pray on irrelevant questions without any meaning. Its a professional site to help people with specific issues and or problems, when people continue to promote such behaviour it doesn't get any better for anyone.

Comment: And it's not a matter of a poorly formed question, it's lack of detail in the question itself. When such data is missing how can you provide a complete answer without any information? So are you saying you can provide good answers that lack detail in itself? That's like saying hey I have a broken bone, can you fix it? Where do you start at?

Comment: I'm glad there's a degree of subjectivism in the determination of a good question. Only two close votes, let the community decide if it should be closed. "How do I solve this?" vs. "I tried this, and this was the problem I encountered, how do I solve this?" can both be answerable. It's a matter of if you have the patience to answer it. This is low-hanging fruit IMO.